# $(this) does not work with waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, jquery-waypoints

The $(this) attribute does not work in connection with the waypoints.js.

My Javascript:

```
$('.dipper').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('test');
}, { offset: '100%' });
```

The strange thing is that this Code is working very well on my website:

```
$('.dipper').waypoint(function() {
    $('.dipper').addClass('test');
}, { offset: '100%' });
```

In this case I am using `.dipper` instead of `$(this)`. You can check it out on my website: http://www.sq-media.de/weboptimierungen/rehfeld

Comment: You forgot surrounding quotes around `.dipper` in your function.

Comment: @D4V1D given the OP states that it works on his site, I would imagine that's just a typo.

Comment: Yep, I just thought it was worth mentioning so it doesn't lead other SO users into thinking this was the mistake (question has been edited since).

Comment: look at the [docs](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) - you should probably work with $(this.element) in waypoints.js

Answer (score 6):

The waypoint method does not run with the same context as the parent jQuery object. If you need this behaviour, you could use `each` to iterate over the `.dipper` elements:

```
$('.dipper').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.waypoint(function() {
        $this.addClass('test');
    }, { offset: '100%' });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question: why affecting `$(this)` to `$this`? Shouldn't the whole point of using `.each()` is to effectively use `$(this)`?

Comment: @D4V1D If that was the case, then the OPs first example would have worked. The `waypoint()` method changes the scope of `this`.

Answer (score 4):

As per documentation provided by waypoint, you will get element ID as

```
  this.element.id
```

So your function will look like -

```
    $('.dipper').waypoint(function() {
        $('#' + this.element.id).addClass('test');
    }, { offset: '100%' });
```

Reference taken from http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/

**Note:** Only additional effort is to add ID to the respective element.